# Access-Control-Allow-Methods and Microsoft Edge, works with Firefox and Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, asp.net-web-api2, microsoft-edge

I'm using superagent to execute a `DELETE` call to my WebApi backend.

The pre-flight call says that the `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` are `*, GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS`. Using the method `DELETE` works fine in Firefox and Chrome, but not Edge (maybe the same with IE?).

Im getting this error in my console:

> SEC7124: Request method DELETE was not present in the Access-Control-Allow-Methods list.

The preflight call for it returns the same in dev-tools for Edge as for Chrome and Firefox. The server is running CORS.

Comment: Maybe the `*` is trowing Edge off. It *is* a valid `Method` token in the HTTP grammar, so it's not wrong to use `*` as a method name, but maybe Edge is inappropriately rejecting it?

Comment: that might be the case, i'll try to eliminate using wild-card, and see if that works. Thanks:)

Comment: @apsillers: you were right. Changed it to only allow post, put, delete and get. Now edge is working:) Please add it as an answer

Comment: As an aside - I've just been trying to debug a similar issue. The CORS request is set to accept GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS but it kept returning a 400 status on MS Edge but not on Chrome/FF. Turns out Edge was requesting a lowercase 'get' in the Access-Control-Allow-Methods rather than GET. Adding extra 'get, post, put' to the server side has fixed this.

Comment: @shunty i saw a lot of craziness like that when i configured my api, so im not really surprised;) Why cant MS ever make something with the same standards as everyone else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently Edge rejects `*` as a value for `Access-Control-Allow-Methods`, despite it being grammatically valid under the CORS and HTTP specifications. Note, however, that `*` does *not* have semantic significance as a wildcard in `Access-Control-Allow-Methods`. It literally refers to an HTTP method with the single-character name `*`. Unless your server actually expects an HTTP method called `*`, there is no reason to include this method name.

Remove the `*` from the list to make your request work on Edge.

Answer (score 3):

IE Edge will also not accept multiple headers, ie.

```
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: PUT
```

and you have to return a single

```
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, PUT
```