# Microsoft Edge not accepting anonymous cross origin?

Tags: javascript, cors, microsoft-edge, facebook-instant-games

On the Facebook Instant Games platform, you can load a user's photo by using the following code:

```
 var playerImage = new Image();
 playerImage.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';
 playerImage.src = FBInstant.player.getPhoto();
```

Setting the crossOrigin attribute to anonymous is required get around CORS and this is recommended by the official Instant Games documentation.

This works on ALL browsers except for Microsoft Edge, which throws errors similar to:

> the origin did not find xxx in the Access-Control-Allow-Origin
>   response header for cross-origin image resource

Is this fixable or should we just tell our users to use another browser? We've received quite a large number of messages from people complaining about not being able to play certain parts of the game and all of them seem to be using Edge. Very tempted to just detect Edge and display a message telling them to use Chrome at this stage.

The response from the server when you request a profile image:

```
access-control-allow-origin: *
cache-control: max-age=1209600, no-transform
content-disposition: attachment
content-length: 12954
content-type: image/jpeg
date: Thu, 14 Feb 2019 12:45:52 GMT
last-modified: Tue, 25 Apr 2017 21:24:05 GMT
status: 200
x-fb-config-version-olb-prod: 449
x-haystack-needlechecksum: 821392244
```

Comment: What does the raw HTTP look like? A standard wildcard origin is `*` not `anonymous`.

Comment: @Liam Just added the response. It's `access-control-allow-origin: *`

Comment: Possible bug in Edge, maybe? https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/8075637/

Comment: Seems [Edge and `access-control-allow-origin` has issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37596680/access-control-allow-methods-and-microsoft-edge-works-with-firefox-and-chrome)